# Django form objects filter

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I want to associate the drop-down lists material and category

models

```
class Demande_Expertise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    material = models.ForeignKey("Material")
    categorie =  models.ForeignKey("Category")     

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, null=True, blank=True, default = None)

class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('category'))
```

forms

```
class Demande_ExpertiseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Demande_Expertise

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Demande_ExpertiseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['material'].queryset = Material.objects.filter(category=Category)
```

no error but filtering don't work.

how to filter `name`  of the model `Category`?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a relation in a queryset by a field by using double underscores (so `category__name` in this case) and passing in whatever you want to filter it by.

```
class Demande_ExpertiseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Demande_Expertise

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Demande_ExpertiseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['material'].queryset = Material.objects.filter(category__name="name to filter")
```

In this case it will filter all of the `Material` objects to those which have a `Category` set to exactly `name to filter`. You can learn more by reading [the Django documentation on retrieving objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects).